Pandas dataframe to sql issues with Boolean values storing as 0 and 1
I am trying to store a dataframe in high has many Boolean columns with True and False values to sql table but when it’s stored to sql using pd.to_sql my Boolean values of Columns gets stored as 0 and 1 .Also when using pd.to_sql I am using styles = dtypes

what rdbms are you using? sqlite?

Oracle sql is the DB I am using

The Oracle RDBMS does not support a Boolean datatype that's the reason your boolean values are infered as 0 and 1
